# Using opencv and gtk+2 together

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi, gtk, gtk2

so i am currently trying to achieve the following: Create a gui for the user were the user can see a livefeed of the webcam and also have two buttons left of the livefeed to start and stop the recording. all this has to run on a raspberry pi.

I am using a basler camera so i can not use the videocapture object but using the pylon sdk (sdk for basler cameras) i managed to grab an image and convert it into a opencv::mat.

however im stuck on two points:

first i do not know how to display an opencv::mat on a gtk widget at all.

the second problem is that i do not know how to get a live stream. I tried to use the g_timeout_add function but then the ui gets unresponsive. it calls the function in background but since i call it every 100ms it seems to be stuck forever in the function and therefore i can not click on any buttons.

i have included some of my code below.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/video.hpp>

#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>

using namespace Pylon;
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void callback(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer labelstatus) {}

gint delete_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent  *event) {
    gtk_main_quit ();
}

static gboolean livefeed_func(gpointer data) {

    Pylon::PylonAutoInitTerm autoInitTerm;
    CInstantCamera camera(CTlFactory::GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice());
    camera.Open();
    GenApi::INodeMap& nodemap = camera.GetNodeMap();
    .
    . Some other pylon related stuff
    .
    CImageFormatConverter formatConverter;
    formatConverter.OutputPixelFormat= PixelType_BGR8packed;
    CPylonImage pylonImage;

    Mat openCvImage;
    cv::Size frameSize = Size((int)width->GetValue(), (int)height->GetValue());
    .
    . Some other pylon related stuff
    .
    formatConverter.Convert(pylonImage, ptrGrabResult);
    openCvImage = cv::Mat(ptrGrabResult->GetHeight(), ptrGrabResult->GetWidth(), CV_8UC3, (uint8_t *) pylonImage.GetBuffer());
    imwrite("tmp_name.jpg", openCvImage);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    //GTK

    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *table;
    GtkWidget *labelstatus;
    GtkWidget *labellog;
    GtkWidget *buttonexit;
    GtkWidget *buttonstart;
    GtkWidget *buttonstop;
    GtkWidget *livefeed;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Table");
    gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 20);

    gtk_signal_connect (GTK_OBJECT (window), "delete_event", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC (delete_event), NULL);

    table = gtk_table_new (6, 6, TRUE);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), table);

    labelstatus = gtk_label_new ("Status: Idle");
    gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(table), labelstatus, 0, 2, 0, 1);
    gtk_widget_show (labelstatus);

    buttonstart = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Start");
    gtk_signal_connect (GTK_OBJECT (buttonstart), "clicked", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC (callback), (gpointer) labelstatus);
    gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(table), buttonstart, 0, 1, 1, 2);
    gtk_widget_show (buttonstart);

    buttonstop = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Stop");
    gtk_signal_connect (GTK_OBJECT (buttonstop), "clicked", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC (callback), NULL);
    gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(table), buttonstop, 1, 2, 1, 2);
    gtk_widget_show (buttonstop);

    labellog = gtk_label_new ("11:31:54: Started Recording\n11:36:54: Stopped Recording");
    gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(table), labellog, 0, 2, 2, 3);
    gtk_widget_show (labellog);

    buttonexit = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Quit");
    gtk_signal_connect (GTK_OBJECT (buttonexit), "clicked",GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC (delete_event), NULL);
    gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(table), buttonexit, 0, 2, 3, 4);
    gtk_widget_show (buttonexit);

    livefeed = gtk_drawing_area_new();
    gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(table), livefeed, 2, 5, 0, 4);
    gtk_widget_show (livefeed);

    gtk_widget_show (table);
    gtk_widget_show (window);

    g_timeout_add(100, livefeed_func, livefeed);

    gtk_main ();

}
```

so if i run this code it will display the gtk window and then be unresponsive and write images until i cancel the process.

So to sum it up:

1. is there a way to execute background tasks in gtk without the ui becoming unresponsive
2. how can i display an opencv::Mat in a gtk window/widget?

Comment: If you want the UI to always be responsive, you'll have to execute background processes in a separate thread.

Comment: you have to have a seperate thread for retrieving OpenCV framebuffer and also use expose event inside a gtk widget to show OpenCV framebuffer. The following post shows how to do it with GTK c++ binding: [Using OpenCV in GTK+ applications](http://www.linkbucks.com/ALfaG)